# Can't start Neo4j cluster -- Write transactions to database disabled

Tags: neo4j, cluster-computing, virtualbox, high-availability

I'm trying to run Neo4j High Availability cluster on three machines, two of which are virtual. I have made a local network between them, here are my config files:

**neo4j.properties** -- the first instance

```
ha.server_id=1 

ha.initial_hosts=[ip.1]:5001,[ip.2]:5001,[ip.3]:5001

ha.cluster_server=[ip.1]:5001

ha.server=[ip.1]:6001
```

**neo4j-server.properties**

```
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA

org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=[ip.1]

org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474
```

**neo4j.properties** -- the second instance

```
ha.server_id=2 

ha.initial_hosts=[ip.1]:5001,[ip.2]:5001,[ip.3]:5001

ha.cluster_server=[ip.2]:5001

ha.server=[ip.2]:6001
```

**neo4j-server.properties**

```
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA

org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=[ip.2]

org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474
```

**neo4j.properties** -- the third instance

```
ha.server_id=3 

ha.initial_hosts=[ip.1]:5001,[ip.2]:5001,[ip.3]:5001

ha.cluster_server=[ip.3]:5001

ha.server=[ip.3]:6001
```

**neo4j-server.properties**

```
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA

org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=[ip.3]

org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474
```

On Windows 8 I run the arbiter instance by double click .\bin\Neo4j.bat and get the console log: "Write transactions to database disabled" with exceptions.

Have I configured instances right? Why it doesn't work?

For slave instances I use Oracle VM VirtualBox with Ubuntu 14.04 on both virtual machines.

Comment: Did you start all three? What exceptions were reported?

Comment: Why are you using an arbiter when you have three regular instances?

Comment: Luanne, I only start the arbiter instance. Exception information goes to console that closes quickly. Where can I watch any logs?

Comment: Stefan Armbruster, how have you find out that all of my instances are regular? And then, how to configure them this way -- one master and two slave instances?